# Is there a way in python to compare strings for unique character

Tags: python, string-comparison

Suppose I have a list of strings

```
['elvis','elo','eels','acdc']
```

Is there a function that accept this string and returns a unique character for each of the strings? For example, in this case, I expect to get

```
['e','l','s','a']
```

Edit: To clarify my meaning.

I want a function that will return an identifier character or string that is based on the input list members. [jme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27515689/596691) answer and [bonit's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27515553/596691) one are a good example.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique character for each of the strings"? How come you choose 'a' from 'acdc', why not 'd'?

Comment: What do you mean by "unique character"?

Comment: There seems to be no clear correlation between your input list and your expected output - can you please explain the requirements?

Comment: What should happen if a unique character cannot be found? e.g. what if the input list is `[ 'eee', 'eee' ]`?

Comment: Do you mean a char for each string that isn't currently representing one of the other strings? So ['abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd'] would output ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']?

Comment: can you explain why you get the output `["e","l","s","a"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Benoît Latinier's interpretation of your question is right (which, it *looks* like it is), then there will be some cases where a unique letter can't be found, and in these cases you might throw an exception:

```
def unique_chars(words):
    taken = set()
    uniques = []

    for word in words:
        for char in word:
            if char not in taken:
                taken.add(char)
                uniques.append(char)
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError("There are no unique letters left!")

    return uniques
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I see your point. There is no built-in for this.

Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems like you want to take the first not already taken character in each string and take one only.

Here is some code to do that

```
def get_first_not_know(l):
    chars = []
    for word in l:
        for letter in word:
            if letter not in chars:
                chars.append(letter)
                break
    return chars
```

If you don't care about order of letters you take, you can do something quicker using sets.

Comment: Plus one for a nice guess (even if the OP meant something else :))

Comment: I think you need to `return chars` here. That said, I think this is what OP wanted, and is a pretty decent solution. I think there will be some cases where grabbing the first possible char from each word will leave you stuck even though a possible solution exists, but this is a pretty good first pass.